# reading tokens misreading simple string - c

Tags: c, string, token

I'm writing a program where I need to read in token by token and detect certain keywords. One of these keywords is "gt" which stands for greater than.

I split the text file into tokens by tabs, newlines, spaces, and returns. Buffer is simply a large char array.

```
 char*  word = strtok(buffer, " \n\t\r");
```

I then have several cases to check for the possible words.  The gt is as follows.  Weirdly enough, this works for other keywords and sometimes even other occurrences of 'gt'.

```
//gt
        if(strcmp("gt", word) == 0){
            type = GT;
            literal_value = 0;
        }
```

However, it isn't getting reached despite a 'gt' being input.  I noticed that when I print, this happens

```
printf("WORD is %s!\n", word);

PRINTS "!ORD is gt"
```

Which clearly isn't right.  If the answer is something obvious please let me know- this bug has been evading me for a long time!

updated fragment:

```
char * word = strtok(buffer, " \n\t\r");

    while (word != NULL){
        printf("word is %s!\n", sections);     //PRINTS "!ORD is gt"

        if(sections[0] == ';'){
            break;              //comment indicated by ';'
        }

        //gt
        if(strcmp("gt", word) == 0){
            type = GT;
            literal_value = 0;
        }
          //...............
         //other comparisons for less than, equal to

        process(&curr, output_file);   //function to process current token
        word = strtok(NULL, " \n\t\r");
        }
```

Comment: We can't even begin to address this question based on the fragments you've presented.  If you want a useful answer then it would behoove you to present a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Can you provide us the entire code fragment that you wrote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer.

The reason you get the output is that you have a ms-dos (or windows) type `.txt` file which has two newline characters. You are catching the '\n'line feed character but not the carriage return character... so your string `%s` is printing a carriage return. That is why the `!` is the first character on the line.

Comment: this completely fixed the issue, I missed a return character- will be accepting in 5 minutes!

Comment: @rubyquartz - glad that this fixed the issue :-)